# Excel VBA TextStream.writeline with Chinese characters

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I am fairly new to VBA and am stumped on how to resolve the "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" error that I am receiving when executing this code.  The cell in question has chinese characters and the code seems to work fine on the english alphabet.  The stream is outputting to a text file.  (should be an xml file in the future, but I still don't have all the correct formatting implemented)

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, stream As TextStream    
Set stream = fso.createTextFile("C:\Users\username\XMLs\" _
   & WS_Src.Cells(c.Row, 5).Value & "_" & WS_Src.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value & "_Feature.xml", True)
```

...

```
stream.WriteLine "<title>" & vbCrLf & "<![CDATA[ " & WS_Src.Cells(c.Row, 6).Value & "]]>" & vbCrLf   & "</title>" 'error is on this line
stream.Close
```

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sytax for using `CreateTextFile` method is something like  `object.CreateTextFile(filename[, overwrite[, unicode]])`
. Where:

- `filename`: Required. String expression that identifies the file to create.
- `overwrite` Optional. Boolean value that indicates if an existing file can be overwritten. The value is True if the file can be overwritten; False if it can't be overwritten. If omitted, existing files are not overwritten.
- `unicode` Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether the file is created as a Unicode or ASCII file. The value is True if the file is created as a Unicode file; False if it's created as an ASCII file. If omitted, an ASCII file is assumed.

And you have omitted the last param here, but incoming text, being `Chinese` is not just `ASCII`. Rather you have to provide a `True` value for that, I mean for `unicode` param. This would definitely solve the problem.

BTW! There are still some factors I can see in the code might cause other run-time errors.

- As you generating filename by joining cell values, make sure no invalid characters is not present in the path string,
- Furthermore, only setting `overwrite` value to `true` is not enough, but also make sure that the folder already exist. Otherwise the procedure would again caught by run-time errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its workign now! just added the extra parameter, thanks. I do know about the filename issues with the cells, and will need to implement some find and replace functions at the start of the macro to deal with charactrs that are illegal in dos filenames and to change stuff to xml formatting.  As for the folder, theres little need for the folder location to change, so I set the path to a folder I created for this purpose.  Thanks again!